# Cumulative sum based on two columns string match

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am looking to create a cumulative sum basis the string match in two columns. Basically if the station id matches/occurs in `start_station_id` then add 1(+1), if it matches in `end_station_id` then subtract 1 (-1). Do a cumulative sum of these values at `start_station_id` level.

So reason why second row (cumulative sum) under output table shows 0 because 3711 occured in first row in `end_station_id` (-1) & the came in `start_station_id` in row 2, so +1. Hence 0 (-1+1)

Below is an example.

[image: example]

```
  df<-structure(list(start_time = structure(c(1567296107.6, 1567296154.219, 
    1567296217.859, 1567296265.919, 1567296297.743, 1567296297.912, 
    1567296439.327, 1567296633.11, 1567296642.817, 1567296883.48), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), start_station_id = c(302, 3711, 3711, 470, 297, 470, 
    470, 285, 285, 470), end_station_id = c(3711, 470, 3708, 383, 
    3711, 383, 297, 3711, 3711, 489)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(
        start_station_id = c(285, 297, 302, 470, 3711), .rows = structure(list(
            8:9, 5L, 1L, c(4L, 6L, 7L, 10L), 2:3), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
        "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
    "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Yes , Looking for cumulative value wrt start_station_id

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand the logic correctly

Comment: If the station id occuring in start_station_id then add 1(+1) in temporary counter, if it matches in end_station_id then subtract 1 (-1) in temporary country. Do a cumulative sum of these values at start_station_id level and display in a new column

Comment: e.g. in the first row, 302 in 'start_station_id', you are checking the whole column 'start_station_id' and didn't find anything and in end_station_id column also didn't find, so it is 0?, then for second value 3711, it matches end_stastion_id, first row, so are you subtracting -1 in the first row again?

Comment: Yes,  I  subtract -1 for 3711 start_station_id counter, for 302 it remains 0. This operation is grouped by start_station_id

Comment: @akrun, to add check 470 start_station_id since it occurs 3 times in start_station_id & 1 time in end_station_id, hence cumulative sum last cell is 2 (3-1)

Comment: I was thinking the logic as `df %>% mutate(indx_pos = n(), indx_neg = -1 * sum(.$end_station_id %in% start_station_id), indx = indx_pos + indx_neg)` may be it is not what you meant

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to get what I want using hashmap concept in R

```
list2env(
         setNames(
                 as.list(rep(0,718)), 
                 df %>% pull(start_station_id) %>% unique()
             ),
         envir = EE
     )

df$new_val <- 0
for(i in 1:nrow(df))
  {   x <-as.character(df$start_station_id[i]);
      EE[[x]]<-EE[[x]]-1;
      #print(EE[[x]])
      df$new_val[i]<- EE[[x]]
      y <-as.character(d$end_stfation_id[i]);
      EE[[y]]<-EE[[y]]+1
     # print(EE[[y]])
}
```